# Console app template missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to test out XMLReader but I just want the output to be simple like the console app template, but this seems to be missing from Visual Studio express for windows mobile.

Is there a way to test things simply just to see if my code is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create class libraries?  If so, use NUnit and write your test code in a unit test method body.

Comment: nunit doesn't work in express. i've resorted to monodevelop to test portions of code for now.

Answer (score 0):

Im a little late to the party but in VS you need create as Console App when first creating website. You cant create a console app after you've created the website